# Use ActiveDirectory authorization with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm implementing corporate website with asp.net mvc and want to use new ASP.NET Identity framework.
Is it possible to integrate ActiveDirectory authorization with ASP.NET Identity? 
Any samples how to do it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to marry Active Directory with Identity. Check out this answer for a complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734478/8644294

Answer (score 15):

- Yes it's possible using a claim based authentication. It's integrated to .Net 4.5 now (before it was called WIF).
- You can use [Thinktucture](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/tree/master/samples/AdfsIntegrationFullSample), which is a very robust authentication provider it has a full example on how to integrate ADFS. Here is a link for it.
- Here is another way to do it for an MVC4 app - [MVC 4 and ADFS integration guide included](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2013/10/01/claims-aware-mvc4-app-using-wif-identity-and-access-tool-in-net-4-5.aspx)
- Here's a solution for [MVC5 Web app using ADFS On-Premises Organizational Auth and Visual Studio 2013 localhost development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374975/mvc5-web-app-using-adfs-on-premises-organizational-auth-and-visual-studio-2013-l)
- If you don't want to use ADFS you can use the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`. It works with Windows authentication and here's an post of using it with Forms authentication - [Chris Schiffhauer - Implement Active Directory Authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412061735/http://www.schiffhauer.com:80/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/):

Comment: What about not using ADFS?

Comment: Look at my update and the example provided in the link.

Comment: I use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider it based on old asp.net  membershipment. I want to switch to ASP.NET Identity

Comment: http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio#orgauth

Comment: Here I see only ADFS and Azure Active Directory

Comment: Not to toot my own horn, but I wrote a blog post on this: https://willwebforfood.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/owin-and-active-directory/

Comment: However I think "ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" is the old way. Here is a guide how to implement a custom ASP.NET identity without EF. Probably you have to do the same for Active Directory, but it seems to be quite a lot of work for such a standard functionality, that should actually be integrated in ASP.NET: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity#rolestore