# AspNet.Identity ActiveDirectory Authorization

Tags: c#, active-directory, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have a very simple implementation of the AspNet.Identity apiservice using Entity Framework that hands out tokens that cam be used to authorize requests through out all the services and web sites.  Users have claims to identify what they are authorized to do within our system. Some of these users (internal users) will have also have AD accounts and rather than have them have to remember different passwords I would like to authenticate through AD for these users then use the AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework to add claims. Ideally if a user is already logged into the domain on there PC they would not even have to enter their password.

How can i get our AspNet.Identity implementation to validate with AD?
I have already seen this question [Use ActiveDirectory authorization with ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427013/use-activedirectory-authorization-with-asp-net-identity) but I am not using the ThinkTecture Identity Server and it seems to be using something other than AspNet.Identity and I do not want to replace our current implementation.

Can anyone give me a course of action or point me towards a tutorial that accomplishes something similar?

Comment: Perhaps this can give you a direction: http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/

Answer (score 0):

It depends. VM, Cloud, Local Machine? If a machine on the network, could be different. Either way you will have to modify your web.config to gain access to your membership provider in order to achieve the seamless route presented in the link below.

This link, 
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication, should help you get in the right direction as to setting up IIS*. Hope this helps.