# Asp.net Identity support for ADFS

Tags: adfs, asp.net-identity-2

We're in the process of migrating our authentication and authorization logic away from the original membership providers. We are currently looking at Asp.net Identity, but no one on the team has experience with this technology. We've been asked to support ADFS in the future and looking to see if this framework directly supports ADFS, which no one on the team has experience with either.
 The only article I've found, http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/ seems to imply asp.net identity will support ADFS as a provider. Are there any other definitive resources for asp.net identity and ADFS?

Regards,
Noobian

Comment: You might find this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427013/use-activedirectory-authorization-with-asp-net-identity) usefull

Comment: I guess my question isn't clear. Does the asp.net identity programming model offer ADFS as an option? Some of the reference links in the above post talk about using WIF. IE Similar to how the membership provider has an API that you programmed against and if needed, you could switch out providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Identity offers an "easy" way to add users and authenticate against them in a SQL DB.

ADFS can only authenticate against AD.

WIF is still supported but older - the OWIN WS-Fed libraries are the way to go these days.

If you want to use ASP.NET Identity have a look at thinktecture's IdentityServer. Offers full support for this plus you can federate with ADFS.