# AD forms Authentication + ASP.NET IDENTITY + ENTITY Framework + unit of work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, active-directory, form-authentication

i have implemented an AD forms authentication to authenticate user. Entity framework + unit of work that act as my abstraction layer between controller and database context. Now, i want to implement user roles for the authenticated user. the user's information and the type of roles are stored in a sql database. my question is, to implement user roles, do i have to use ASP.Net identity and how do i go about doing it? i was unable to find any useful articles around that shows me how to do it. any help to point me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: I think there is what you want at this discuss : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427013/use-activedirectory-authorization-with-asp-net-identity

Comment: the links are not very helpful, but it's ok. i found some resources and i'm going to try them out. however, keep the answer coming guys