# Handling Users in a Entity Framework project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I need some advise regarding the software design related handling and persisting the user data across multiple views in my project.
First, let me give you the overview of my project.

The project is split into two components. The WebApp is responsible for displaying the front end to the user. 
The WebApi, using Entity Framework code first approach, is responsible to interact with the database.

I've to implement the Users functionality. Such as Login, Logout and ensuring views accessible to the users on the basis of the roles assigned.

As per our requirement, only Active Directory users are granted access to the application. Is there a way, could anyone suggest a tutorial, how I could implement this using asp.net Core Identity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427013/use-activedirectory-authorization-with-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Identity Create Web Application project with Individual User Accounts.
Check out this link [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=vs0)